# ¿Cómo recorrer un resultado de una consulta JSON para obtener un resultado concreto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, diccionarios

Estoy trabajando con un resultado de una consulta en formato JSON. El siguiente contenido es un ejemplo de la estructura del contenido:

```
[
    {
        'id': '1234', 
        'title': '1234', 
        'concepturi': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/1234', 
        'label': 'hello', 
        'description': 'article of beneficts to say hello'
    }, 
    {
        'id': '5678', 
        'title': '5678', 
        'concepturi': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/5678', 
        'label': 'hello', 
        'description': 'hello to the city'
    }, 
    {
        'id': '9012', 
        'title': '9012', 
        'concepturi': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/9012', 
        'label': 'hello', 
        'description': 'hello to life'
    }
]
```

Todo este contenido lo tengo guardado en la variable llamada `content = result['search']`.

Lo que pretendo hacer es obtener aquellas uri que mediante una comprobación en el campo description en que si no se encuentra la palabra *article*, devolver la primera uri que encuentre.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
def pick_preferred(self, content):
    for ind in range(len(content)):
        if "article" not in content[ind].description:
            return content['concepturi']
```

El problema es que me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'description'
```

No entiendo el por qué de este error cuando teóricamente si que se encuentra en el diccionario y no se como puedo solucionarlo.

Comment: Sinceramente no se nada de Json, pero si lo que buscas hacer es acceder a una clave de un diccionario, la forma correcta sería `content[ind]["description"]`. Lo pongo entre comillas, ya que la clave que buscas es casi seguramente una cadena.

Comment: Inicialmente lo tenia puesto como has comentado, pero me salta el siguiente error: `KeyError: 'description'`. Por eso lo he puesto de la forma en que esta ahora.

Comment: Que raro... Corregí un poco tu código y lo probé y a mi no me da ese error (que significa que la clave que buscas no está en el diccionario). Por si te preguntas, las correcciones que hice solucionaban otros problemas, pero no este. En escencia, tu ejemplo es una lista de diccionarios, y eso lo entiendo. Estás seguro que todos los diccionarios de tu json tienen la clave `'description'`? Te recomiendo revisar eso.

Comment: Acabo de revisar y sí, los 15 diccionarios que obtengo como resultado contienen la clave `'description'`.

Comment: Sería mucho texto que agregar si te pido el resultado completo? Puede que esté mal escrita la clave en alguno de los diccionarios.

Comment: Sí, hay mucho contenido pero lo he revisado y esta bien escrito en todos los casos. La verdad es que no entiendo el error cuando simplemente es lo que has comentado que en esencia es una lista de diccionarios.

Comment: Yo tampoco lo entiendo... no se me ocurre nada. Suerte con solucionar el error a los demas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos!!

Answer (score 0):

EL primer error está en esta línea

```
if "article" not in content[ind].description:
```

En python los indices se colocan dentro de corchetes cuadrados, debe ser:

```
if "article" not in content[ind]['description']:
```

Y el segundo error en la siguiente línea:

```
return content['concepturi']
```

Has omitido la referencia numérica del diccionario en cuestión. Debe ser:

```
return content[ind]['concepturi']
```

Apenas se encuentra una coincidencia, el `return` terminará la función, por lo que supongo debes ser consciente que esa función siempre retornará un solo valor, si es que encuentra alguno, claro.

Comment: Yo también note esos errores en el código, sin embargo, el error por el que @drakitus pregunta se debe a que la clave `'description'` no es encontrada en los diccionarios en los que itera.

Comment: El error se debe a que no encuentra `content[ind].description` @DanteS. Y tal como se nota, `description` no es un atributo por lo que es obvio que va a saltar ese error. Esto me parece cierta confusión con Javascript.

Comment: Leiste los comentarios debajo de la pregunta? El error no se debe solamente a eso.

Comment: Con las correcciones que propongo @DanteS. esa parte de código funciona. Si hay otra cosa que no está descrita, entonces el problema [no es reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), lo cual hace la pregunta [candidata para cierre](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), a menos que el OP edite su pregunta y especifique con más detalle su problema.

Comment: Me temo que por desgracia el problema no es reproducible. Es lo que creo debido a lo que el OP me dijo. En resumen, parece que hay al menos un diccionario que no tiene la clave `'description'`. Sin embargo, el OP revisó y no encontró ninguna ausencia o mal escritura de dicha clave. Extraño no?